# No notification sound with empathy

Tags: gnome, empathy

I'm using `ubuntu oneric` with `empathy 3.2.0.1` and `gnome-shell 3.2.2.1-0ubuntu0.1`. When I use empathy with unity, I receive a notification sound every time someone send me a message. But When I use empathy with gnome-shell, I only receive a visual notification on the bottom-center of the screen, without any sound.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get sound back by reinstalling sound-theme-freedesktop and ubuntu-sounds package:

```
sudo aptitude reinstall sound-theme-freedesktop ubuntu-sounds
```

Then restart empathy, everything works.